# h264 restream works when i have no audio in ffserver conf but does not work when i try to add audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-processing, ffserver

I am trying to restream an h264 video stream from a camera. All works well when I have NoAudio in my conf file. However when i add audio, even the video stream does not work. Has anyone ever encountered thiss?

ffmpeg  -i rtsp://********* -s 320x240 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -s 320x240 -ab 64k  http://*****:8091/feed1.ffm

Comment: did you were able to figure this out?

Comment: Similar question (also unsolved): https://superuser.com/questions/1297272/i-get-only-audio-or-video-with-ffserver